# How can I list components of a list individually within a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Within the following pivot table I would like to separate the element within a list/tuple to be displayed vertically and without the [] brackets of a list.

[image]

So instead of displaying [o,t] in group C/2 it would display vertically with B row having more height and excluding the [] and , like below? (except without the large space between them)

o

t

code below. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

item_list=["m","n","o","p","q","r", "s", "t", "u", "v"]
group_list=["A", "B", "B" ,"C", "D","E", "D", "B" ,"B", "D"]
rank_list=[1,1,2,3,5]*2

df = pd.DataFrame({"Items":item_list, "Group":group_list, "Rank":rank_list})
df.pivot_table(index="Group", columns="Rank", aggfunc=list,fill_value='')
```

the output is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['Items'].stack().apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x])).unstack().stack(0)
```

Output:

```
Rank       1    2    3    5
Group                      
A     0    m  NaN  NaN  NaN
B     0    n    o    u  NaN
      1  NaN    t  NaN  NaN
C     0  NaN  NaN    p  NaN
D     0    s  NaN  NaN    q
      1  NaN  NaN  NaN    v
E     0    r  NaN  NaN  NaN
```